# How to find launcher for two separate version of Python?

Tags: python

I've installed 2 versions of Python: 2.7 & 3.5 on my Mac. And only one Python Launcher app appeared.

When I try to run a TkInter based script with the Python Launcher that is there, it is always finding the TkInter in the directory `/Library/Frameworks/Python Framework/Versions/2.7`.

Since I want to run the app in 3.5, so I want my program to find things in `/Library/Frameworks/Python Framework/Versions/3.5`

Comment: I'm GNU/Linux, not Mac, but did you try opening the terminal and using `type python` for Python 2 and `type python3` for Python 3? Did you try launching your app as `python3 appname.py` for v3 or `python appname.py` for v2? What about the shebang line at the beginning of the script?

Comment: For macs, there is a app called "Python Launcher" which is supposed to type the command line for you. I know how to type the command of course, but I need to figure out how to do it with the easy way. So yeah.

Comment: Can you manually create a new entry for it, with a distinct name, and give it the command to use? I sometimes have to do what on GNU/Linux to get the launcher if I've "installed" an application without an installer (e.g. Eclipse IDE).

Comment: Sorry, but what is "It". The Python plugin or the PyLauncher?

Comment: The launcher, since it's what you were talking about.

Comment: But excuse me, how to do it? And with what?

Comment: If it is a long story, put in in answer form please.

Comment: Is it finding the Python executable there or just the Tkinter binaries? If the latter, could it be a `PATH` problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python Launcher preferences, check the option "Allow override with #! in script" (it's right under where you select the interpreter). At the top of the script, put `#!/usr/bin/env python3`. More [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#miscellaneous).

Comment: What is it: 'env python3' or 'envpython3'?

Comment: @Jemoka the one with the space. You could use copy/paste.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can have a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), which enable you to switch python interpreter between different versions.

For example, you can set global python interpreter as 3.5 by:

```
pyenv global 3.5
```

or you can just set local python interpreter as 3.5 by:

```
pyenv local 3.5
```

which will run python program using v3.5 when running python in certain path.